# In Django, how can one access file fields in forms.py?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-file-upload

I have this form class in forms.py in my Django application:

```
class EmailForm(EmailFormWithoutAttachment):
    attachment = forms.FileField()
```

I would like to access the file uploaded in forms.py for validation via a clean function to validate its name.

```
def clean_attachment(self):
    if self.data['attachment'].name == "someFileName.txt":
        raise forms.ValidationError('This file is not allowed.')
    return self.data['attachment']
```

However, the problem is that an error notes that "attachment" is not found in "QueryDict." I am binding request.FILES to the submission form. I am also using enctype="multipart/form-data" on my forms. I was wondering what is the proper way to access FileField data in forms.py.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `self.cleaned_data['attachment']` instead of `self.data['attachment']`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but using self.cleaned_data['attachment'] gives me this error: "KeyError at /email/ 'attachment' " Could it be that I am not passing the file data into the form?

Comment: I'm not on a computer right now that i can test this on, but can you try using self.cleaned_data.get('attachment') and see how that pans out? Also, check for possible spelling errors! I'll try to get a better answer as soon as i can get on my other computer.

Comment: Also can you post the definition of the `EmailFormWithoutAttachment` class please?